# How to get EF Framework to generate this group by query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I tried a few different ways and I am not impressed with the generated output query. It seems so inefficient. It needs to be efficient and shouldn't bring back all the rows into the app layer

```sql
select year(datetaken) as yr,
       month(datetaken) as mth,
       day(datetaken) as dy,
       count(*) as totalpics
from photos
where photos.dateTaken <= @cutoffdate
group by year(datetaken), month(datetaken), day(datetaken)
order by yr asc, mth asc, dy asc
```

LINQ query:

```
var query = ctx.Photos.Where(p => p.DateTaken <= maxCutOffDate)
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.DateTaken.Year, p.DateTaken.Month, p.DateTaken.Day })
    .Select(grp => grp);
var results = query.ToList();
```

Comment: What does seems inefficient means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select only the grouping key (`grp.Key`):

```
var query = ctx.Photos.Where(p => p.DateTaken <= maxCutOffDate)
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.DateTaken.Year, p.DateTaken.Month, p.DateTaken.Day })
    .Select(grp => grp.Key);
var results = query.ToList();
```

**Edit**

Or, including the `count` of totalpics:

```
var query = ctx.Photos.Where(p => p.DateTaken <= maxCutOffDate)
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.DateTaken.Year, p.DateTaken.Month, p.DateTaken.Day })
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        Date = grp.Key,
        TotalPics = grp.Count()
    });
var results = query.ToList();
```

Comment: I will take that answer though it is not what I expect. It doesn't seem efficient though but it does the job. I have an index on datetaken on the photos table.  Would it be possible to have it generate the group by instead of distinct

Comment: @palKhoa: Maybe the `distinct` will disappear and become a `group by` when you use an aggregate function like `Count()`, see my Edit above.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the key properties through `grp.Key` and the count through `grp.Count()`.

```
var query = ctx.Photos.Where(p => p.DateTaken <= maxCutOffDate)
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.DateTaken.Year, p.DateTaken.Month, p.DateTaken.Day })
    .Select(grp => new 
                   { 
                       grp.Key.Year,
                       grp.Key.Month,
                       grp.Key.Day,
                       Count = grp.Count()
                   });
var results = query.ToList();
```